# CSS3 Child Menu not showing on focus

Tags: html, css, navigation, position

I am able to display the first sub menu on focus, but the second sub menu does not display. I have tried setting the css properties to `display: block` and have also tried changing the positioning, but I am obviously missing something.

This was started as a Sass project and I could probably make it a lot easier to find the problem by removing a lot of the redundant `ul li ul li` in the CSS but I am still having the same problem.

I have posted a jsfiddle setup with the CSS and HTML I am using. Any help resolving the second sub menu would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/nulimitz/uxfposgc/

HTML:

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
 <div class="logo">Website</div>
 <div class="mobile-nav">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
 </div>
 <ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-item">Link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```css
.nav-main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 70px;
    color: #fff;
}
.nav-main .logo {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.nav-main > ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #444;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > a:focus ~ ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #444;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > a:focus ~ ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-main > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. It works on manual focus but the anchor element doesn't react to focus.

Add tabindex to your code.

```
<a tabindex="1"></a>
<a tabindex="2"></a>
```

This would make the anchor elements respond to focus.

So your code would be:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a tabindex="1"></a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a tabindex="2"></a>
 </li>
  ...and so on
</ul>
```

**Edit:** You can even change the order of the focus to the anchor element by changing the order of the tabindex.

For eg:

```
<a tabindex="2"></a>
<a tabindex="1"></a>
```

This way the second anchor element will be focused first on pressing *Tab* and then the first anchor element.

Comment: That's strange because the first submenu works on focus and on hover, it's the second sub menu that doesn't. Let me give your idea a shot though.

Comment: @user3080988 yes the first one works but that's it. The other ones don't behave like *Tabs*. For that if you use tabindex you can make all of them behave like the way you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have 3 problems here:

1) You can't have a second dropdown with :focus, because you only focus 1 item at time, so when you focus the second (click) you will lose the first focus and everything is going to close. 
Also the overflow:hidden will hide this second level ul.

2) Is the accessibility of this, you will have problems to navigate with tab keyboard.

3) You have specifics class for each elements, use it and reuse in you css for optimal performance proposes.

To archive this I recommend you use js (or jquery) or hover in LI element too, more or less like this:

```
.nav-main .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu,
.nav-main .dropdown a:focus + .dropdown-menu{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
    transition: all, 25ms, ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uxfposgc/3/

Also check this question [Accessible HTML5/CSS3 dropdown menu without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349670/accessible-html5-css3-dropdown-menu-without-javascript)

Comment: I got your suggestion to work. Now just to clean up up as you suggested and build it with sass and position the secondary menu at the top of it parent li.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't upvote you, but you solution does work. Thanks again!